# SC14430 Microprocessor programming help

Tags: integrated-circuit, programming, microprocessor

I have a SC14430 Microprocessor, and I want to know what software I should use to read and write to it. It has the standard SRX STX GND pins. I have attached a couple of images for reference. Thank you[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Have you looked in the datasheet or manual to see what it recommends? What circuit board do you have that has this on it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is on a Wireless Intercom Headset, and there is no available documentation on it. The chip manufacturer was bought out by another company and now that company leads to this site https://www.renesas.com/us/en

Answer (score 1):

I found [Logitech Skype Phone](https://www.tinytransistors.net/2020/12/05/logitech-skype-phone/) where someone has taken a Skype handset apart and posted a picture of the same chip:

[image]

Unfortunately that website contains:

> **There’s no documentation available on the SC14430**, but it’s likely to be similar to the SC14434 which is commonly used in DECT-enabled internet routers. It probably contains a microcontroller and the essential baseband processing needed to implement the DECT protocol. After all, this is really just a DECT phone, although connecting to a base station plugged into a computer rather than into a phone line.

That website has actually decaped the SC14430 and posted some pictures of the die, and says:

> The logo area shows a 2003 copyright date, which was well before the Sitel spin-out. Also, the part number is identified as “SC1443X”, suggesting that it’s part of a family of similar parts including the SC14434. An online search confirms that this is the case, and that these chips contain a 16 bit microprocessor (**based on the CompactRISC architecture from National**) and an integrated DSP.

Not sure if the above helps to try and find how to read and write to the SC14430.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I will follow your advice and see if I can find anything on SC14434.